# GSL1680-Capacitive-Touchscreen-Controller

Tags: touch

I got buydisplay GSL1680 based board lcd using in MIKROE and I am not able to initialise the GSL1680 Capacitive Touch Controller. I also followed the code that is given on buydisplay.com. May be there is a problem in loading firmware. I'm not getting a fix of this problem. Any help?

This is the code:

```
void TOUCH_Init(void)
{
  CTP_WAKE = 1;
  delay_ms(50);
  CTP_WAKE = 0;
  delay_ms(50);
  CTP_WAKE = 1;
  delay_ms(50);
  _GSLX680_clr_reg();
  delay_ms(50);
  _GSLX680_reset_chip();
  delay_ms(50);
  _GSLX680_load_fw();
  delay_ms(50);
  _GSLX680_startup_chip();
  delay_ms(50);
  _GSLX680_reset_chip();
  delay_ms(50);
  _GSLX680_startup_chip();
  delay_ms(50);

}
```